# eclipse property tester for empty project or folder

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a popup-menu contribution for .txt file in a project:

```
<menuContribution
        allPopups="false"
        locationURI="popup:com.XXXX.ui.view.navigator?endof=group1">
      <command
           commandId="com.XXXX.ui.commandid2"
           style="push">
          <visibleWhen
              checkEnabled="false">
           <iterate
                 ifEmpty="false"
                 operator="or">
              <or>
                 <adapt
                       type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile">
                    <test
                          property="org.eclipse.core.resources.extension"
                          value="txt">
                    </test>
                 </adapt>
                 <instanceof
                       value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder">
                 </instanceof>
              </or>
           </iterate>
        </visibleWhen>
     </command>
```

As you can see, currently I have enable for folder also. But wanted to make invisible for a blank folder and empty project. No clue **how to apply property tester for an empty folder or Project**. Any pointer would be much helpful.

Comment: You need to write your own propery tester and check members() function on IFolder

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard property tester available which tests if the folder or project is empty.

You could write your own property tester for this using the `org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters` extension point.

Comment: Thanks Greg it was helpful!